# Won't write dict row to csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Below is my code:

```
if(row == current_account):
                            edited_account = {'id':current_account_id,'price':current_account_price, 'amount':current_account_remainder_amount, 'type':"BUY", 'date':current_account_date}
                            new_account = {'id':s, 'price':last_order_price, 'amount':last_order_amount, 'type':"SELL", 'date':last_order_date}

                            writer.writerow(edited_account)
                            writer.writerow(new_account)

                            print("*** EDITED ACCOUNT: " + str(edited_account) + " ***")
                            print("*** ADDED ACCOUNT: " + str(new_account) + " ***")
                            self.update_log("*** EDITED ACCOUNT: " + str(edited_account) + " ***")
                            self.update_log("*** ADDED ACCOUNT: " + str(new_account) + " ***")
```

For some reason, it wont let me write a Dict that has an exponential float in the amount field, for eg. 1.4935380525642888e-10. All other floats work fine however.

For example, it prints out:

```
*** EDITED ACCOUNT: {'amount': '0.03826056483395195', 'type': 'BUY', 'price': 1395.38, 'id': '46ce341a-dfae-40c3-9815-a2f7bebc0810', 'date': '1430324015'} ***
*** ADDED ACCOUNT: {'amount': 0.0015329392870640016, 'type': 'SELL', 'price': 1395.59, 'id': '703890df-cf1d-4ae0-aab9-0b6be357df25', 'date': '1430327386'} ***
```

and when I check my csv file, both these accounts are there.

However, in one case it printed out:

```
*** EDITED ACCOUNT: {'amount': '0.00010000055698286583', 'type': 'BUY', 'price': 1394.95, 'id': "<class 'str'>", 'date': '1430341136'} ***
*** ADDED ACCOUNT: {'amount': 2.3518644466467972e-08, 'type': 'SELL', 'price': 1396.41, 'id': '879aac41-0cc2-406f-a9e7-c73f7476e9de', 'date': '1430341892'} ***
```

and when I checked my csv file only

```
{'amount': '0.00010000055698286583', 'type': 'BUY', 'price': 1394.95, 'id': "<class 'str'>", 'date': '1430341136'}
```

was there...

This is strange, because, I wrote a simple test script to write {'amount': 2.3518644466467972e-08, 'type': 'SELL', 'price': 1396.41, 'id': '879aac41-0cc2-406f-a9e7-c73f7476e9de', 'date': '1430341892'} to a csv, and it was able to do so, but I can't think of any other reason why it won't add this Dict to a csv in the first script. My reasoning is this: it manages to print out *** ADDED ACCOUNT: {'amount': 2.3518644466467972e-08, 'type': 'SELL', 'price': 1396.41, 'id': '879aac41-0cc2-406f-a9e7-c73f7476e9de', 'date': '1430341892'} ***
It follows that:

a) writer.writerow(new_account) must have been executed....because it is in the same 'if' block.

b) it is a valid Dict object.

Comment: Do you call `close` on the file (explicitly or with a `with` statement)? And had the program already passed the `close` before you looked at the file?

Comment: By the way, at some point you've somehow got the str type instead of a string in one row, you're mixing floats and string representations of floats in the same column... So I think you've got other problems earlier in the code.

Comment: Please reduce your program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.